# Adding text to the front - Python

Tags: python

I have the below code

```
Test1 =  Price[Product.index(TestABC)]+   AddQTYPriceA

print Test1
print "try this test" + Test1
```

When it needs to print Test 1 it gives the correct answer. I want to try and add text to the front of it and so I have entered print "try this test" + Test1

For the second print command it gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\data.py", line 78, in <module>
    print "try this test" + Test1
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

Can someone assist how I can get text to appear at the front.

Greggy D

Comment: `Test1` is a float value, and Python won't cast it to a string automatically. If you want to concatenate it with a string, you must typecast it with `str()`

Comment: Note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends reserving `CapWords` for classes, and using `lowercase_with_underscores` for local variables, it keeps your code clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to concatenate the string and float you need to cast the float as a string using the `str()` function.

```
print "try this test " + str(Test1)
```

Or you could use the `.format()` string method:

```
print "try this test {0}".format(Test1)
```

Both of these methods are documented on the python [string built-in type page](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html).

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
print "try this test", Test1

# let's assume that Test1 is equal to 2.5, you will get : 
>>> try this test 2.5
```

no need to concatenate the strings, let python do the job ;)

EDIT : 
As mentionned by Lattyware, python will automatically add a space between the 2 parts of the resulting string.

Comment: Note that this will add a space, which may or may not be what was wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got my wrist slapped for using the traditional approach.

Use the [string.format](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) approach as it's very flexible:

```
print "try this test {0}".format(Test1)
```

str.format() takes an arbitrary number of arguments, and maps sequentially to the {slot} given in the string. So you can do:

```
"{0} {1} {2}".format("test", 1, 0.01) # => "test 1 0.01"
```

Nice and simple!

So only do the following if no one is looking:

```
print "try this test %f" % (Test1)
```

Comment: -1. Using the modulo operator for string formatting is deprecated, use `str.format()`. Also, give some explanation of what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Lattyware: They new formatting style may be preferred, but the old style **has not been deprecated**.  See [Old String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations), specifically "there are no current plans to deprecate printf-style formatting."

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Sorry, my poor choice of wording, still, it's highly recommended for new code, and there is no reason to encourage use of the old method at this point, anyway, removed my -1 for the update.

Comment: @Lattyware: Guido [prefers](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-February/116912.html) the new formatting, but "for consistency's sake, if you add formatting code to an existing module that uses the old style, please stick to the old style. And to avoid disasters, also please don't go on a library-wide rampage of wholesale conversions. The time to start using the new formatting is when writing new modules or packages, or possibly when doing a major refactoring/upgrade of an existing module or package."

Comment: @Lattyware: If your read through [this thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-February/116789.html) on the Python Developers Mailing list, you'll see that not everyone likes the new style formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example:

`print "try this test %s" % str(Test1)`

which allows you to put text at the beginning or somewhere else in relation to Test1.

Comment: -1. Again, Using the modulo operator for string formatting is deprecated, use `str.format()`. Also, give some explanation of what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Lattyware: They new formatting style may be preferred, but the old style has not been deprecated. See [Old String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations): "there are no current plans to deprecate printf-style formatting."

Comment: As I said in the other post, you are entirely correct, I was wrong to say it's deprecated, however, I would still argue that encouraging use of the old method is a really bad idea, as the new method is the much better option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the output of the Test1 to the same data - print can handle any data type but the `+` operator only handles the same type.

Options are:

- cast whatever output Test1 gives to string using `str()`
- define a method to handle adding of Test1 to other things to return string.
- make it the Test1 class actually generate the whole string output so there would be no need to concatenate it, you can implement `__str__()` method
- use many of the options to format the output

But I believe that the main point to take home is that the `+` is not overloaded in python as it is in other languages and one needs to explicitly cast different types.

Example what needs to be added to your Price class to be able to use your print code unmodified:

```
class Price(object):
    def __add__(self, x):
        return '%s %s' % (self, x)
```